# Antidifferentiation involving natural log

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}d\sigma = \ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}\right)$$

Sigma is not a constant.

Have I found the correct antiderivative?

Comment: Is the integration with respect to  $d\sigma $?Otherwise the answer is surely wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is with respect to dσ

Comment: That's the anti-derivative with respect to $d(2\pi \sigma^2)$ but but not to $d\sigma$.  You're going to have to do integration by parts.

Comment: .. D'oh! $\sqrt{\sigma^2} = |\sigma|$ (as per Emilo's answer) so no need for integration be parts (except in the trivial sense of subbing a function for a constant times a function)

Comment: If @EmilioNovati's answer works, click the check mark next to the voting button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your integral is:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi \sigma^2}}d \sigma
$$
then you can write it as:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi }\;|\sigma|}d \sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi }\;} \int \frac{1}{|\sigma|}d \sigma
$$
so the antiderivative is:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi }}\ln |\sigma| + C
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} d\sigma &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \frac{1}{|\sigma|} d\sigma\\
& =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{ln}(|\sigma|)+c
\end{align}$